# Can't find upper case letter in URL using Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
(href[\s]?=[\s]?)(\"[^"]*\/*[^"]*\")
```

using the following Test String:

```
href="http://mysite.io/Plan-documents"
```

I get two capturing groups.  One with the href= and the other is everything past that.  Now I want to only display matches where there is an uppercase letter anywhere in the second capture group.  I tried:

```
(href[\s]?=[\s]?)(\"[A-Z]*[^"]*\/*[^"]*\")
```

to try and only have this regex come back with URL's that have uppercase in them.  No luck. Regardless if I modify the test string as:

```
 href="http://mysite.io/plan-documents"
```

I still get a match.  I only want to match on the href string if there any at least one uppercase in the string past the href=.

Thanks.

Comment: What tool or language are you using? The regex tag on its own is ambiguous.

Comment: Are you only using this regex to find URLs that contain uppercase letters? If so, you probably don't need any capture groups.

Comment: Anyway, your regex is matching more than you expect because you're using the negated character set `[^"]*` (any number of non-double-quotes). Lowercase characters aren't double quotes, so they match. Also you quantify your uppercase characters with `*` instead of `+` or some other non-zero number, so the pattern matches even when there are none of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get the right matches because in your second capturing group all what is between double quotes uses a quantifier `*` which matches 0 or more times.

First the engine matches 0+ times `[A-Z]*`. It is not present but it is ok, because of the 0+ times quantifier.  Then the next part `[^"]*` will match until right before it encounters the next `"`

The following `\/*` is not there but is also ok because of the 0+ times quantifier followed by `[^"]*` which is also ok.

What you might do instead is first match not an uppercase until you match an uppercase and then match until the closing double quotes.

```
(href\s?=\s?)("[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z][^\s"]*")
```

**Explanation**

- `(href\s?=\s?)` Capture group, match href= surrounded by optional whitespace char
- `("` Start capture group and match `"`

  - `[^A-Z\s]*` Match 0+ times not an uppercase or whitespace char
  - `[A-Z]` Match 1 uppercase char
  - `[^"\s]*` Match 0+ times not `"` or a whitespace char
- `")` Match `"` and close capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DLjSR0/1)

Without using groups, you could use:

```
href\s?=\s?"[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z][^\s"]*"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/odrCp9/1)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was spot on.